# Camera Albums Directory in android devices

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, android-camera

My android app (created by air) saves the token shots at /DCMI/ address but it dosent show them in gallery albums.

How can I find androids photo album directory address so I can save the pictures in them and enable them to be shown in the photo galley

this is my code :

```
var directory:String;
if (rad1.selected){
    directory = "mnt/sdcard/DCIM/SHEKAR/";

}
else {
    directory = "/DCIM/Camera/";

}
var savePath:String = directory;
```

i need replace cameraroll directory to  "/DCIM/Camera/"  tanx .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_DCIM

Also, make sure that there's no .nomedia file in your directory or one of the parents.